# In C programming language, Is it correct to return a local char[] variable by converting it to const char *?

Tags: c

I understand that it is bad to return a local variable from a function which is stored in stack segment. What if I convert a char[] to const char *, then return it, is it considered as a good practice? If so, what segment will the const char * be stored in?

something like this:

```
const char * foo() {
    char str[32];
    sprintf(str, "Hello");
    return (const char *)(str);
}
```

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: damn didnt read enough, it was about returning it. DAMN x)

Comment: No.  `str[]` is history.

Comment: C does not specify segments.  So segments depend on your platform and compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting to `const char*` does nothing. It still points to the `str` value, which becomes invalid when you return because it's on the stack.

Adding the `const` just makes it so that whatever uses the return value can't modify the data pointed to by the pointer (unless they cast off the const). But since it points to a returned function's stack space, once `foo` returns, any access to the pointer is undefined behavior, so the point is moot.

Comment: What if I define str as "static char str[32]"?

Comment: @TonyWen Do you know what `static` does when it's used in a variable declaration in a function?

Comment: as I know, a variable declared as static should have its memory kept through program execution.

Comment: @tonywen: it is safe to return a pointer to a local static, but it is not a good idea unless the variable is never modified (for what I hope are obvious reasons.)